# XML schema for a complex type and I want an attribute on it

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

In your xml wisdom, have you a idea on how to define the type for `“bDead”` to be? (`type=”xs:Boolean”`)

```
<bDead>0
<xdn>state</xdn>
       <xdv>alive</xdv>
</bDead>
```

Here’s the schema. Where/how would I specify the type and ranges for bdead?  I don’t think that I can..

```
<xs:element name="bDead" >
<xs:complexType mixed="true">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="xdn" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="xdv" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Hitesh.  You can provide more information about your question by editing your post (link under the tag list) or commenting on a specific answer (links at the bottoms of answers).  If one of the answers solves your problem, please mark it "accepted" by clicking the outline of a check mark to its left.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question properly, you want `bDead` to be an `xs:Boolean` with mixed content?  The `<xs:simpleContent>` element is probably what you want inside your `<xs:complextType>`.

As Lord Torgamus says, w3schools is a pretty good place. I uses [w3c.org](http://w3c.org). It can be harder to understand sometimes, but they are the source of the standard. As for XML-Schema, their "Part 0" of the standard document is a kind of primer. http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what you're asking for; do you mean the text of `bDead`, which is 0 in your example?  What is `bDead` supposed to be, an integer?

In general, it seems like you want something related to XML schema restrictions.  w3schools has a good page about those [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp).